# Strange result on page_impressions_by_paid_non_paid facebook metric over API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, metrics

When i make this call  to facebook API returns a strange result:

https://graph.facebook.com/{idpage}/insights/page_impressions_by_paid_non_paid/day?format=json&since=1398902400&until=1401580800&access_token={access_token}

This is result:

```
     "values": [
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-01T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-02T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-03T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-04T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-05T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-06T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-07T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-08T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-09T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-10T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-11T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-12T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-13T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-14T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-15T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-16T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-17T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-18T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-19T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-20T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-21T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-22T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-23T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-24T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-25T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-26T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-27T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-28T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-29T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-30T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": [

           ],
           "end_time": "2014-05-31T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 6,
              "paid": 1,
              "unpaid": 7
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-01T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 7,
              "paid": 4,
              "unpaid": 7
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-02T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 56,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 56
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-03T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 67,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 67
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-04T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 34,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 34
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-05T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 3,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 3
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-06T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 5,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 5
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-07T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 7,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 7
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-08T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 7,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 7
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-09T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 6,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 6
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-10T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 4,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 4
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-11T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 776,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 776
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-12T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 776,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 776
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-13T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 776,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 776
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-14T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 556,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 556
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-15T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 665,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 665
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-16T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 88,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 88
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-17T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 66,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 66
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-18T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 66,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 66
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-19T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 66,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 66
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-20T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 77,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 77
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-21T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 66,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 66
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-22T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 5,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 5
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-23T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 3,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 3
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-24T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 2,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 2
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-25T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 1,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 1
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-26T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 1,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 1
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-27T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 5,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 5
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-28T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 4,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 3
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-29T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 1,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 1
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-30T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
           "value": {
              "total": 3,
              "paid": 0,
              "unpaid": 3
           },
           "end_time": "2014-05-31T07:00:00+0000"
        }
     ]
```

every day have two value. is that correct returns in this way or is it a bug in facebook API?